# Ошибка при вызове любого из методов из сервлета

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, glassfish

По какой то причине выкидывает ошибку при вызове любого стороннего метода из сервлета. До сего часа проект работал нормально. Есть бекап проекта(рабочей версии), но при запуске выдает ту же ошибку. 
Последнее что делал, почистил локальный репозиторий maven.

```
[2016-10-22T11:47:22.704+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1477126042704] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[loginController]: Servlet.service() for servlet loginController threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bpmw.web.controllers.user.LoginController.doPost(LoginController.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Думаю что проблема где-то в настройках Glassfish или IDEA, возможно я случайно удалил какие то необходимые для работы библиотеки.

В дебаге выяснил, как только доходит до вызова метода из другого класса приложение вылетает.

Восстановление рабочих копий проекта не помогает.

Comment: Вам же написано какая ошибка и даже в какой строчке какого класса. `java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bpmw.web.controllers.user.LoginController.doPost(LoginController.java:65)` Вот и думайте как такое случилось. А нам-то что гадать, не видя исходников, даже кусочков малых.

Comment: Проблема точно не с кодом, а в настройка. Я использую бекап рабочей версии. (Сохраняю проект ежедневно).  Так вот все версии отказываются работать, не помогла даже переустановка гласфиша с заново выставленных конфигами. Куда смотреть не знаю, уже все испробовал.

Comment: Если сломался код, а настроек правильных никто не знает, значит надо попытаться по коду понять, что ему нужно. А настройки они у всех могут отличаться от стандартны, даже очень сильно. Какзалось бы сервлет он и в африке сервлет, но у меня отличия от ваших, начиная с ntbeans вместо inteliji, wildfly вместо glassfish, ant вместо maven. Скинуть вам свой конфиг? Так у вас вообще всё ляжет и уже не подымется никогда.

Comment: Вот код, если есть возможность посмотрите пожалуйста https://github.com/petrovtsev/BPMW?files=1

Comment: Если исходник соответствует логу, то даже не знаю, что могло за-null-ить listViewsModel. Если допустить, то он таким нулевым внедряется... Но разве такое может быть? Просто так без предупреждений внедрить null? Ладно бы из продюсера какого. Или это из-за проблем инъекций выше по цепочке? Но там вверху сервис ejb. Если с ним проблемы, то приложение даже не разворачивалось бы сервером. Наверное это какой-то другой исходник. Или где-то в returnViewsActiveUser, но лог почему-то закончился на LoginController. Выше/ниже есть ещё лог трейса?

Comment: Я бы погуглил на предмет бага в глассфише. Почему он инжектит нулл. Начиная с версии 4 оракул не шибко и правит баги. Поробуйте вместо glassfish http://www.payara.fish/

Comment: Лог соответствует исходникам. Вчера решил прикрутить Java Mail API , с отправкой сообщений разобрался быстро, а с получением возникли сложности. В процессе неоднократно менял конфиги (pom.xml, подгружал-удалял зависимости и настройки glassfish для java mail) в один момент понял что приложение больше не работает. В дебаге доходит до 59 строчки класса com.bpmw.web.controllers.user.LoginController. Если строчку закоментить встает на первом обращении к другому классу. Такое ощущение что сломался CDI. Только как?

Comment: Все настройки глассфиша сделал с нуля. А отказываются работать даже архивные .war файлы (которые ранее 100% работали). Ежедневно помимо комитов на гитхаб сохраняю копию проекта с рабочим .war на диске. Уже не знаю куда смотреть.

Comment: Ближе к 10 буду дома скину весь лог и попробую заюзать payara.fish. Большое спасибо за участие помощь!